# MBP not detecting change in external display when switched with an HDMI switch

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, monterey

I have a Macbook Pro (16" 2019 intel running Monterey 12.6 in clamshell mode). I have two monitors (One 4K, one FHD) and a simple HDMI switch to choose which one to use. The MBP connects to the HDMI switch with a USB-C to HDMI cable.

If I start on the 4K monitor and hit the HDMI switch, the FHD monitor gives me an "unsupported" message until I unplug and re-connect the cable connecting to the MBP.

If I start on the FHD monitor and hit the HDMI switch, I can't go higher than FHD resolution on my 4K monitor until I unplug and re-connect the cable. I can see that the MBP still thinks I'm connected to the FHD monitor in display settings.

I bought the switch to help reduce wear due to lots of unplugging and re-connecting to switch monitors.

Is there any way by software I can force the MBP to think I've unplugged and re-connected the cable, or to force it to re-evaluate what it thinks the connected display is?

Comment: What's the brand and model of the switch?

Comment: It's a [JSAUX HDMI 2.0 4K 60Hz Switch](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08GG4914P)

Comment: I've never found inexpensive HDMI switches to work well, if at all. We use [this splitter](https://www.amazon.com/Orei-HDMI-Duplicator-Splitter-OREI-dp-B0891L7XDH/dp/B0891L7XDH) to send high-quality HDMI to two 4K (75" and 55") Samsung displays in a classroom. Most of the time, the 75" is used for normal sized classes, but large classes need the 55" for desks around a corner without a sight-line to the 75" screen. With this device, just turn off the screen you don't want to use. At US$25, it is only a little more expensive than the switcher you are having difficulty with.

Comment: The switch seems to work OK, just that the Mac doesn't seem to know it's switched. My requirement is for a switch that doesn't require power, plus it's a pain to reach the power button or the outlet of the monitors without a ladder, so your suggestion unfortunately wouldn't work for my situation :(